# What's the relationship between snabdom, hyperscript and Vue 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, virtual-dom, hyperscript

I'm trying to understand Vue with more depth and have done some reading about Vue 2's virtual DOM implementation and came across the mentions of snabdom and hyperscript.

My understanding is that Vue 2 uses a fork of snabdom to implement its virtual DOM. Then there's also the render function which calls the `h` to create virtual node.

So how is the virtual node (hyperscript) related to snabdom? Seems like they do the same thing.

Vue2's `h` in render function:

```js
new Vue({
 render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: What's the premise for the question? Vue has the functionality that snabdom and hyperscript libs offer and borrowed from them at some point but there's no relationship between them. They don't come together.

Comment: I have added more context to my question.